# Find set of vectos such that it has the same coefficient with respect to two different bases.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say that we have two sets $B=(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ and $C=(c_1, c_2, c_3)$. These two sets represent two different bases of real vector space $V$. We know that these two sets (their elements to be precise) satisfy the following:

$$ c_1 = 2b_1 - b_2 - b_3 \\ c_2=-b_2\\ c_3 = 2b_2 + b_3 $$

Find all vectors that have the same coordinates with respect to both bases.

This is what i have so far:

Let $x \in V$ ( $x$ is a random vector from $V$), if $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ then this vector meets the requirement given here if:

$$x_1 c_1 + x_2 c_2 + x_3 c_3=x_1 b_1 + x_2 b_2 + x_3 b_3 $$

if we express coefficients of second base in terms of the first one we have:

$$2x_1 b_1 + (-x_1-x_2+2x_3) b_2 + (-x_1+x_3) b_3=x_1 b_1 + x_2 b_2 + x_3 b_3$$

which leads me to conclusion that $x_1=0,  x_2=x_3$

Which means that any vector from set $span{(0,1,1)}$ meets these requirements. This might be correct, but i have no intuition on this, how come this is possible, this means that it can happen that we have one same vector and we choose two different bases but we get same coordinates, this confuses me, i'd appreciate any intuitive explanation of this.

Comment: Simple example: $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,-1)$ form an ordered basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Every vector with $z=0$ in the standard basis has exactly the same coordinates in this basis, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base $C$ is obtained from the base $B$ using the matrix:
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0\\
-1&-1&2\\
-1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and you want the eigenvectors of this matrix for the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ ( if they exists).

In this case $\lambda=1$ is really an eigenvalue of the matrix and you have found the corresponding eigenspace.

Comment: i am really sorry but i cant see relationship between eigenvalues of the matrix and the question i asked

Comment: Without loss of generality you can assume that $B$ is the standard basis and you are searching a vector $1vec x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ ( in this standard basis) such that $M\vec x=\vec x$ (. This means that the vector $\vec x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ for the eigenvalue $1$.